# CharacterRange oddity

Tags: list-manipulation, named-characters

CharacterRange documentation says that it returns a list. However, if I define

```
letters[n_] := CharacterRange["\[Alpha]", "\[CurlyPhi]"][[;; n]]
```

and then ask for `Part[letters, 3]`, I get `Part::partd`. If I ask for `Last[letters]` I get `Last::normal`. What gives?

Comment: try `n=4; Part[letters[n], 3]`

Comment: OK, this one is on me for using code I don't completely grok. That last bit with the n in the definition of letters, what is it doing? Are you redefining it with your statement?

Comment: jamesson, see [tutorial/DefiningFunctions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html)

Comment: If you really don't understand what functions are (in the programming sense), then it's time to go through a basic tutorial: https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/  There is a minimum level of expected Mathematica knowledge before asking on this website.

Comment: No, trust me, I know what a function is :). I have spent the past 2 hours reading about Mathematica scope, it is... interesting.

Comment: TBH I never thought about lexical vs dynamic scoping but in Mathematica and python dynamic scoping seems inevitable. I am quite impressed that they managed to implement lexical scoping in Mathematica, at all.

Comment: `letters` is just the name of the function.  You can call the functions using `letters[10]` (or another number than 10, but it must be a integer number).  The function returns a list.  You can only take a `Part` of a list, not of a function name.  That last bit isn't actually true: you can take a `Part` of any *compound expression*, see [Everything is an Expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html). The function name in Mathematica is an *atomic* symbol with no parts.

Comment: But this question has nothing do to with scoping ... you simply tried to take a part of the function name, not of the function's return value.  Yes, scoping in Mathematica is a bit unusual.

Comment: No, I understand this is not a scoping issue, I was just referring to the fact that I understand functions

Answer (score 4):

While e.g., `letters[5]` (or any other integer between 1 and 22) is a list, `letters` is not.  Colloquially, `letters` is a function, which is implementing in Mathematica as a symbol with [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html).

You can think of DownValues as rules which are applied during the sequence of evaluation, so that `letters[5]` evaluates to `{"α", "β", "γ", "δ", "ε"}`.

In fact, you can query the DownValues of `letters` with fairly readable results:

```
DownValues[ letters ]
```

> ```
> { HoldPattern[letters[n_]] :> CharacterRange["α", "φ"][[1 ;; n]] }
> ```

<sub>([`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html) is just a way of making sure the left hand side of the rule doesn't evaluate before the rule can be applied.)</sub>

Your problem was two-fold:

1. No subpart of `letters[[3]]` is of the form `letters[n_]`, so the DownValue couldn't apply
2. More noticeably, `Part` immediately tries to evaluate, even if its first argument has insufficient length/depth, which results in your error.

If you'd like to use the syntax `letters[[3]]` to return `"α"`, you can instead redefine letters:

```
ClearAll[ letters ]  (* Remove DownValues *)
letters = CharacterRange["α", "φ"];

letters
```

> ```
> {"α", "β", "γ", "δ", "ε", "ζ", "η", "θ", "ι", "κ", "λ", "μ", "ν", "ξ", "ο", "π", "ρ", "ς", "σ", "τ", "υ", "φ"}
> ```

```
letters[[3]]
```

> ```
> "γ"
> ```

Fun fact:  while `SetDelayed` (`:=`) statements are stored as rules in `DownValues`, `Set` (`=`) statements are stored in [`OwnValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwnValues.html) :

```
 OwnValues[ letters ]  (* after using `=` rather than `:=` *)
```

> ```
> { HoldPattern[letters] :> {"α", "β", "γ", "δ", "ε", "ζ", "η", "θ", "ι", "κ", "λ", "μ", "ν", "ξ", "ο", "π", "ρ", "ς", "σ", "τ", "υ", "φ"} }
> ```

Comment: Very cool, I must study this